# Select item from drop down list using text

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

I need to select an item from drop down list using its text. The problem is when I use below code, it selects the exact name only. What I want is:

```
Name
--------
abc
def
xyz
```

This is what I tried to do.

```
ddlSup.SelectedIndex = ddlSup.Items.IndexOf(ddlSup.Items.FindByText("a"))
```

When I write 'a' I want to get abc, in my case am getting nothing. Thanks.

Comment: > *"This method does not do partial searches or wildcard searches"*, description of MSDN: [ListItemCollection.FindByText Method - MSDN - Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    For Each Item In ComboBox1.Items
        If Item.ToString.Contains(TextBox1.Text) And TextBox1.Text.Trim <> "" Then
            ComboBox1.SelectedItem = Item
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text.Trim = "" Then
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If
    Next
```

you can modify this code, instead of using `Contains` function you can also use `StartsWith` or some string manipulation function available.